# Freeze money in Visa / Mastercard cards

Tags: mastercard, visa-api

Is it possible to freeze money on the card, before buying.

And after delivery of the goods, write off the money from the user's card.

Is it possible to implement such functionality through API?

Thanks for any information :)

Comment: I don't think that you can interact with creditcards through a pure API. This is a really sensible topic.

Answer (score 1):

In the payment processing world, "Freezing" money on a card is called *Authorization* and "Write off" is called *Capture*.

The timeframe, from the time of authorization, in which capturing the funds is allowed usually depends on the card brand and your payment provider API limitations.

Many payment providers offer the ability to authorize funds prior to capture, and generally speaking, the time period for capturing the funds after authorization is 3-10 days.